# Error when runnning Scala app using Typesafe Activator

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator, typesafe, typesafe-stack

When I try to run an app using Typesafe Activator, I get this error:

```
Loading main class information...
launching discoveredMainClasses task
Loading project definition from /project_path/project
/project_path/build.sbt:7: error: not found: value EclipseKeys
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource
^
Type error in expression
```

What is wrong? There is my build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

And build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript

seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)

seq(com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings: _*)

EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource

EclipseKeys.withSource := true

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oF")

libraryDependencies += "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"

name := "myproject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

Comment: I came here trying to figure out why I got something like the described error when generating Idea project files in Activator.  I ended up deleting the Eclipse plugin from project/plugin.sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your project/plugin.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt.plugins" % "sbt-onejar" % "0.8")
```

**Update:**

Activator has own file "activator-sbt-eclipse-shim.sbt"
It contains:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")
```

Remove "com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" from plugin.sbt.

I changed it to 2.4.0 - and the problem was solved. But after restart activator it again restore 2.3.0 - but the error did not occur any more.

Then I generated project for eclipse/idea. Both finished with success.

Comment: it was already there, except for the one-jar version that was 0.7 in my case. But anyway, it didn't work... :-(